# Running a python script against a bunch of S3 files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a python script that I want to run on S3 files and send the output to another S3 bucket.

Now I could kick off an EC2 instance and interact using `boto` to do this and that's fine.  But this doesn't seem to have an automatic way of shutting down the EC2 once the processes are complete (I'm going to be operating on about 100GB worth of data so I don't want to sit there and watch it).

The data pipelines of AWS seem attractive in that they scale appropriately and release resources when done.  Which is great.  But I can't seem to find a way to run a python script in a pipeline.  The ShellCommandActivity seems closest but I'm not able to figure out how to set it up such that I can have the proper virtual environment built (with the appropriate packages, etc).  Trying to figure out the best way to achieve this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have your script self-terminate your instance when it's done.

Comment: @MattHouser could you elaborate on that?  I haven't seen anything on how to do that

Comment: Have your script issue a terminate or stop command at the end to kill or stop your instance.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2015-10-01.html#terminateinstances

Answer (score 0):

The resources Data Pipeline brings up have Python installed on them. You can just use a ShellCommandActivity and run Python. Here is an example pipeline running a ShellCommandActivity: https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/helloworld

You can substitute the script with something like:

```
python -c 'print "Hi"'
```

Or if you have your Python scripts on S3 you can download and run them

```
wget https://s3.bucket.url/script.py
python script.py
```

Comment: How do I send S3 files as input to python?  Ideally I'd like to run a python script on everything in S3

Comment: What kind of script are you trying to run? Is reading from S3 the issue?